# Making uploading to github easily for ruby project

Tags: git, ubuntu

I'm working on a Sinatra project alone. Every day or even more often I upload the code to github by saying

```
git add .
git commit -m "my comment"
git push origin master
```

I know this question probably is not related to ruby but anyway: how do I make this routine easily? I'd like simply say kind of: `"github-commit "my comment" "` and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that you can be flexible, I would suggest having some short [git aliases](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) that you would use.

For instance, to accomplish what you show in your question, perhaps the commands could be as presented here:

```
gaa
gc "Awesome changes to my code"
gpm
```

It would be less typing, 8 characters minus the comment string as compared to your github-commit command, and yet still flexible.  And I based the commands on the mnemonic 'git add all' and 'git commit' and 'git push master'

You can [define aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) in your .bashrc, for example, by following this pattern:

```
alias gpp='git pull --rebase && git push'
```

Though you will likely need a shell function for accepting an argument for your `gc` functionality, or be presented with an editor (my preference) to place your commit comments in.

Answer (score 1):

Write a .sh script ?

Something like this :

```
#push.sh
git add .
git commit -m $1
git push origin master
```

Then you can do push.sh "your commit message"

(just to give you an idea, not tested)

Comment: it doesn't not allow to use whitespaces for some reason, it'll give the errors then. `./commit.sh "comment1 comment2 comment3"
error: pathspec 'comment2' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'comment3' did not match any file(s) known to git.`